# How do I keep the order of my inner join in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, window-functions, sql-max

I have the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM Posts P 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ThreadId FROM Posts ORDER BY Time DESC) R 
ON P.Id = R.ThreadId;
```

This command selects threads who contain the newest replies. Unfortunately the order of the threads seems to be random. I want the threads to be ordered by the newest replies. In other words: I want my selection to keep the order which I used inside my inner join.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried switching it, so threadids are done in the "from" segment, and then join the posts onto that?

Comment: Cool idea but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql 8.0+ you can use `MAX()` window function in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Posts
ORDER BY MAX(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY ThreadId)
```

For prior versions use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p1.* 
FROM Posts p1
ORDER BY (SELECT MAX(p2.Time) FROM Posts p2 WHERE p2.ThreadId = p1.ThreadId)
```

You may also want to add as a 2nd argument in the ORDER BY clause `, Time DESC`.

Comment: This solved my problem and seems very elegant. Thank you.

Comment: Bonus points for not adopting my "inner join" approach, but finding the most effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your join needs to group and select the last post per thread.  The order needs to go on the outside query (not the subquery).

```
SELECT *
FROM Threads AS t 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ThreadId, MAX(Time) AS LastPost
    FROM Posts
    GROUP BY ThreadId
    ) AS r ON r.ThreadId = t.ThreadId
ORDER BY LastPost DESC
```

You can use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN if you want to exclude threads that have no posts (if that is even possible).

Answer (score 0):

you could change the order of your query like this

```
    SELECT  ...
    FROM    BrandsProducts
    INNER JOIN Brands ON BrandsProducts.brandid = BrandsProducts.brandid
    WHERE   ...
    ORDER BY ...
```